# Convert .sav(spss) file to .csv file using c#

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, spss

Can i Convert an spss(.sav) file to a .csv file by using C#. Here i want to browse 1 .sav file and i need to generate .csv file of the same.Can anyone provide any link or code for the conversion.

i have some 100 spss files so i need to create a console app which will take each file from the parent folder and generate the corresponding csv file for each sav file

Comment: which library do you use to open the spss file?

Comment: @DanielW. Actually i don't want to open the file i have some 100 spss files so i need to create a console app which will take each file from that folder and generate the corresponding csv file in some path.

Comment: @DanielW.i don't know any library is available for this,can u help me please.

Comment: There are some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150586/how-to-open-spss-data-files-in-excel)

Comment: @PeterSmith : in this they are using some online tools or software for conversion but i need some libraries which will support in c#

Comment: Why not use `Process.Start("pspp-convert", "input-sav output.csv");`?

Comment: If (and **only if**) you are fine with GPLing your code, you could have a look at PSPPs source.

Comment: You can find information about SPSS SAV files [here](http://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000469.shtml). Should be possible to forge this spec into C# code.

Comment: As @PaulKertscher says you can use PSPP in command line mode which you manage from C#

Comment: @PaulKertscher: Am sorry am new to c# so am not understanding what is PSPP and how can i use this for my purpose

Comment: @user3501613 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

#### 1) Use a library

[There seems to be a library to read SPSS files](https://github.com/TNSGlobal/SPSS-.NET-Reader).

You can install the NuGet package *SpssLib* and create a `SpssReader` object from a `FileStream`

```
using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead("spss-file.sav"))
{
    var spssReader = new SpssReader(fileStream);
    // read variable names from spssReader.Variables and store to CSV
    // read records from spssReader.Records and store to CSV
}
```

#### 2) Hand-code the solution

If you can't use the library for whatever reason, you may hand-code a solution.

2.1) Have a look at PSPP

If (and **only if**) you are planning (or at least fine with) releasing your code under the GPL, you can have a look at the PSPP source code. Anyway, if you can't GPL your code, **Don't. Do. It.** Do a clean-room implementation instead, since otherwise you'll always be on slippery grounds.

2.2) Have a look at the spec

There is a [documentation](http://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000469.shtml) of the SAV file format online. It may take some time, but you may eventually figure out how to convert this to CSV.

#### 3) Use PSPP

If you have no problem shipping a GPLed software (or are able to download the files on demand somehow), you can make use of PSPPs console application. PSPP is a GNU replacement for SPSS, which aims at (but does not, yet) providing the funcitonality that SPSS provides. Obviously it comes with a handy little CLI tool `pspp-convert` ([see the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/html_node/Invoking-pspp_002dconvert.html)). You can invoke it via the command line with

```
pspp-convert input.sav output.csv
```

With the help of the `Process` class you're able to start another process (i.e. program in this case). If `pspp-convert` is located in the current directory or in any directory that's in the `PATH` variable, converting a file to CSV is a easy as

```
public ConvertSpssFile(string inputFile)
{
    var outputFile = Path.ChangeExtension(inputFile, "csv");
    Process.Start("pspp-convert", $"{inputFile} {outputFile}");
}
```