# How to convert .sav file into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, spss

How do you convert .sav into .csv, or .sav into pandas DataFrame? Is there a direct way or doing this or a package that can do this?

Comment: Which .sav format are you asking about?  Which program or library was used to create the  .sav file?

Comment: It's an old SPSS file, I just want to manipulate it with Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [pyreadstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647006/is-there-a-python-module-to-open-spss-files/20873154#20873154) module, you can find some code snippet to start on [the github page](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#basic-usage).

Comment: I've followed the code and get an error,    "from .pyreadstat import read_sas7bdat, read_xport, read_dta, read_sav, read_por, read_sas7bcat
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: did you install the module using `pip`?

Comment: Why would this make a difference? I just use Pycharm interface and manually install these libraries from there

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat/issues/33) can help you

Answer (score 6):

GNU PSPP project (replacement for the proprietary program SPSS) has a helper tool to do this online - https://pspp.benpfaff.org/

To do this locally
1. Download GNU PSPP - http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/get.html
2. Use command line to do the conversion

```
pspp-convert <input.sav> <output.csv>
```

Similar question - [How to open spss data files in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150586/how-to-open-spss-data-files-in-excel)